# Bean is not found on @EJB injection

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, ejb-3.0

I'm experimenting with EJB3.2 on Glassfish 4.0.
I'm also not very experienced in writing EJB applications, so there is a high prob for stupid errors.

I reduce my classes to the necessary:

```
@Stateless
@WebService
public class SomeJob {

    @EJB MyService myService;

    public void doSomething(){...};
}

@Stateless
public class MyService {

    @EJB AnotherEJB anotherEjb;

}

@Stateless
public class AnotherEJB {

}
```

Wenn I call the SomeJob.doSomething() over the WebService Tester functionality provided by glassfish I see a stacktrace and I'm directed to the ServerLog.

In the ServerLog I find a naming Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=some.url.zvagent.anotherEjb.MyService/anotherEjb,Remote 3.x interface 
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1683)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
```

What I don't understand is, why a Remote Interface is searched? I havent declared one. Why should I need one. I don't want complex configuration. The application will not have any outside clients. It should be stand alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem was a missing library that prevented an EJB to get initialized and therefore could not be injected into another bean.

**General Solution Statement**: If Injection does not work, check the print outs of the server on start up. The server will report what EJBs have been initialized/registred.